# Getting same style in another page when click to login

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am having a login page for user generated by devise gem.where I removed the registerable from model for only login not for signup.I have also generated an admin which gives default login credentials for user in seed.rb file.I have done some css work in login page. next I have generated an employee page for further process for users.

Here my doubt is the styling part what I have done in login page is also coming in employee page. I dont want that so I wrote some condition in application.html.erb

```
<% unless user_signed_in? %>
    <%= render 'layouts/heading' %>
 <% end %>
```

The method is defined in application.controller.rb

```
def user_signed_in? %>
     render :layouts => 'application'
 end
```

I tried a lot by changing conditions but it is still displaying or showing errors.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you're using "device gem", but since you're talking about authentication, I assume you mean "devise"?

The user_signed_in? method is a helper which should be provided automatically by devise, and you should be able to use it in your views. You shouldn't need to define it in the application controller.

You probably want to make sure you do "before_filter :authenticate_user!" in the relevant controller (you can use the ":only" option if you only want this to apply for certain methods).

It's difficult to give any more information because you haven't said what errors you are getting. I assume you're getting some kind of syntax error on the definition of the "user_signed_in?" method, since you have an invalid "%>"on the end of the line, which I guess you copied-and-pasted from an ERB file.